# Dividir datos de un df, en datos de otro df, acorde a una condición

Tags: python

Tengo una base de la siguiente forma:

```
#df1:
Index   var1 var2 var3 condicion
  0       a   b     c      A
  1       d   e     f      B
```

```
#df2:
Index   var1 var2 var3 condicion
  0       g   h     i      B
  1       j   k     q      B  
  2       l   m     n      A  
  3       o   p     q      B  
  4       r   s     t      A  
  5       u   v     w      B  
 ...     ... ...   ...    ...
```

Necesito dividir los valores de df2 en los valores de df1 acorde a la "condición" (para var1, var2 y var3).
Necesito un nuevo df (o el mismo) que realice la siguiente operación: (Sean las letras de la "a" a la "f" numeros reales).

```
#df3:
Index   var1 var2 var3 condicion
  0     g/d  h/e  i/f      B
  1     j/d  k/e  q/f      B  
  2     l/a  m/b  n/c      A  
  3     o/d  p/e  q/f      B  
  4     r/a  s/b  t/c      A  
  5     u/d  v/e  w/f      B  
 ...     ... ...   ...    ...
```

He intentado cosas como lo siguiente, sin exito.

```
variables = [var1, var2, var3]
for i in variables:
    df2[i] = np.where(df2['condicion']==df1['condicion'],df2[i]/df1[i],df2[i])
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a proponer esta solución, de seguro encuentres una mejor.

• Definir `df3` como un `DataFrame` vacio.

• Iterar sobre `df2` y generar un `dataframe` reducido (a un registro) por cada condición.

• Guardar en `df3` los resultados de cada división.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[],columns=['var1','var2','var3','condicion'])

for index,row in df2.iterrows():
    
    result = df1[df1['condicion']==row['condicion']]
    
    var1 = row['var1']/result['var1']
    var2 = row['var3']/result['var2']
    var3 = row['var2']/result['var3']
    
    df3.loc[index,'var1'] = var1.iloc[0]
    df3.loc[index,'var2'] = var2.iloc[0]
    df3.loc[index,'var3'] = var3.iloc[0]
    df3.loc[index,'condicion'] = row['condicion']
```

De esa manera debería arrojar el resultado deseado

Comment: Funcionó, solo corregí en tu código:
```
    var2 = row['var2']/result['var2']
    var3 = row['var3']/result['var3']
```
Muchas gracias!